# Iseries Navigator SQL Performance Monitor for traditional rpg programs

Tags: ibm-midrange

SQL performance monitor is good, but I need  to find the file reads and writes of a traditional rpg program, I don't have the source code.
Exists a similar tool for file reads and writes?
OS version 7.1

Miguel Lagos

Comment: Can you clarify `reads and writes` ? E.g., do you want 'physical' or 'logical' reads/writes? And are you wanting **performance** monitoring or **database** monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

To compare an old school rpg program writes  and reads

```
DSPFD FILE(mydatalib/*all) 
      TYPE(*MBR)           
      OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)     
      OUTFILE(QTEMP/Zbefore)
```

run program

```
DSPFD FILE(mydatalib/*all) 
      TYPE(*MBR)           
      OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)     
      OUTFILE(QTEMP/Zafter)
```

then compare the two outfiles.  You can compare the writes, reads, updates, opens, deletes, etc.  by query the qtemp/zafter and qtemp/zbefore